# AWS C++ SDK Logging on Windows - where are the logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-cpp

I am trying to work from this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/logging.html, but I am not seeing any log output anywhere?

Is default logging in the AWS SDK supposed to write to a file on Windows? Or to the Event Viewer? Or to DebugView maybe? stdout/stderr?

Test code:

```
AWSOptions.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Trace;
Aws::InitAPI(AWSOptions);

Aws::Utils::Logging::InitializeAWSLogging(
    Aws::MakeShared<Aws::Utils::Logging::DefaultLogSystem>(
        "AwsLogTest", Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Trace, "aws_sdk_"));

Aws::Utils::Logging::LogSystemInterface* LogSystem = Aws::Utils::Logging::GetLogSystem();
LogSystem->Log(Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Info, "TEST", "THIS IS A TEST");

Aws::Utils::Logging::ShutdownAWSLogging();
Aws::ShutdownAPI(AWSOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind .. it does indeed log to a file in the current working directory.